# No output info on .JSP from MySQL DB, Spring MVC, Hibernate, JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

I'm trying to output some information from table `users` on my JSP page, but there is no output there.
**Here is my controller method:**

```
@Autowired
private UsersService usersService;

@RequestMapping(value="/user**")
public String getUserProfile( ) {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("userInfo");
        List<Users> userInfo = usersService.userInfo("Oleg");
        mav.addObject("userInfo", userInfo);
    return "user";
}
```

**Here is my DAO method**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Users> userInfo(String username) {
    Transaction tx = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String query = "select users.username, users.name, users.surname, users.email, users.gender, users.age, users.weight, users.height, users.sport, users.place from users where users.username LIKE '%s'";
    List<Users> userInfo = session.createSQLQuery(String.format(query,username)).list();
    tx.commit();
    return userInfo;

}
```

**Here is my Service layer method**

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Profile Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <br />
 <br />
 <br />
 <h1>User profile page !!!</h1>
 <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="j_spring_security_logout" />
 <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Log out" /> <input type="hidden"
   name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
 </form>

<c:forEach var="users" items="${userInfo}">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>Username</td>
   <td>${users.username}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>First Name</td>
   <td>${users.name}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Last Name</td>
   <td>${users.surname}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Email</td>
   <td>${users.email}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Gender</td>
   <td>${users.gender}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Age</td>
   <td>${users.gender}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Weight</td>
   <td>${users.weight}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Height</td>
   <td>${users.height}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Sport</td>
   <td>${users.sport}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Place</td>
   <td>${users.place}</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</c:forEach>


</body>
</html>
```

When i'm starting my project and opening my JSP, i have no output from my DB. Help pls!

Comment: For starters, it's not a service-layer method, it's a JSP. Also, instead of returning the userInfo from DAO method, did you atleast iterate through it and printed what it contains? If not, then go and try that first. Also frame your question bit properly.

Comment: And why should it. You construct a `ModelAndView` and do nothing with it, so basically you allocate only memory. You are returning a `String` which is only the view, either return the `ModelAndView` instead of a `String` or add the `Model` as a method attribute and add the data in there.